# randomly Access violation in unmanaged DLL

Tags: random, pinvoke, marshalling, access-violation

in native DLL, I have:

```
ReturnMode Decoder::Decode(int16 samples[], int num_samples, char** hypothesis){

char *hypstr = NULL;

try
{
        // some other...

        if (s3_decode(&decoder, NULL, &hypstr, NULL) == 0)
        {

            *hypothesis = (char*)CoTaskMemAlloc(strlen(hypstr) + 1);
            strcpy(*hypothesis, hypstr);
        }


        if (hypstr != NULL)
        {
            free(hypstr);
            hypstr = NULL;

        }

}
catch (...)
{
    return FatalError;
}


return Ok;}
```

EDIT: that call in C#:

```
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

            // some other 

            while (!Stopflag)
            {                   
               IntPtr Hypothesis;
                if ((Result = DecoderWrap.Decode(mDecoder, samples, num_samples, out Hypothesis)) == ShProxy.ReturnMode.Ok)
                {
                    var hypothesis = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Hypothesis);
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hypothesis))
                    {                            
                        hypothesis = hypothesis.Trim();
                        ConvertAsciiToUnicode(ref hypothesis);
                        // this is an event 
                        TextReceived(hypothesis, 0);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Fatal("Cannot do decode");
                    break;
                }
            }
            });
```

and imported this way:

```
    [DllImport("ShenavaDec.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    static public extern ShProxy.ReturnMode Decode(IntPtr pDec, short[] samples, int num_samples, out IntPtr Hypothesis);
```

frequently decode method call but AV randomly occurred in s3_decode API in native DLL.
now i want to know where is my mistake?
is it related to marshaling data or no. 
thanks.

Comment: `out string Hypothesis` is wrong. Has to be `out IntPtr Hypothesis`, and manual marshalling.

Comment: thanks David but result is same. used Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Hypothesis);

Comment: Clearly there are other errors but you didn't provide any details of how the function must be called, or show how you did so.

Comment: @David Heffernan, updated call routine.

Comment: You aren't getting this. It's not enough just to pass arguments of the right type. For instance, if you pass an array, you might be expected to allocate it to a certain length. Or maybe it matters what values are passed in an int argument. Nowhere in the question do you address the **semantics** of the function.

Comment: The odds that you pass a correct `pDec` are never very good.  Allocating a C++ object needs to be done by a C++ compiler, it is the only one that knows the real size of the native object and knows how to properly call the constructor of the class.  Much the same when it needs to be destroyed.  Write a C++/CLI wrapper instead.

Comment: if i understand your mean,  mdecoder is an instance of decoder class and decode method get input samples and sample's number then decode them to hypothesis and return it.

Comment: @Hans Passant pDec allocated with C++ compiler. create & destroy it  in dll. otherwise i have this problem before create a class.

Comment: Clearly there's a defect but since the question omits the important detail you will have to solve the problem yourself.